# How does defining a function nested in another work?

Tags: python-3.x, function

In the [Python implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm#Python) of the [Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm), a function is defined while being nested in another function. Part of the code:

```
def draw_line(img, p1, p2, color):
    """Draws an anti-aliased line in img from p1 to p2 with the given color."""
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    dx, dy = x2-x1, y2-y1
    steep = abs(dx) < abs(dy)
    p = lambda px, py: ((px,py), (py,px))[steep]

    if steep:
        x1, y1, x2, y2, dx, dy = y1, x1, y2, x2, dy, dx
    if x2 < x1:
        x1, x2, y1, y2 = x2, x1, y2, y1

    grad = dy/dx
    intery = y1 + _rfpart(x1) * grad
    def draw_endpoint(pt):
        x, y = pt
        xend = round(x)
        yend = y + grad * (xend - x)
        xgap = _rfpart(x + 0.5)
        px, py = int(xend), int(yend)
        putpixel(img, p(px, py), color, _rfpart(yend) * xgap)
        putpixel(img, p(px, py+1), color, _fpart(yend) * xgap)
        return px
```

How does this work? Why didn't the programmer just define the code somewhere else and then call it in this function? If this function where to be called in a loop to draw multiple lines, wouldn't it be more efficient to just, as I said, define the nested function somewhere else?

Comment: If you want to call `health_health` from outside of the method it probably shouldn't be in `health` in the first place. Put it directly into `Humans`.(As a few stylistic notes, consider calling your class `Human`, not `Humans`, find a better name for `health_health`—maybe `print_health`?—and consider putting your `health` logic into an `__init__`.)

Comment: Why are you defining `health_health` inside the method? It should just be a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class Humans():
    def health(self, weight, height, age):
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        self.age = age
    def health_health(self):
        print(f'''This human is {self.age} years old; weighs {self.weight},  
        and has a height of {self.height}''')
Harar = Humans()
Harar.health(1,2,3)
Harar.health_health()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because you are calling the function from the [class definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax), as opposed to the [initialized object](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects). You can do two things to fix this:

Call the function from the object that has been initialized:

```py
class Foo:

    def bar(x):
        print(x)

a = Foo()
a.bar(10)
```

Or, define the function as a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```py
class Foo:

    @staticmethod
    def bar(x):
        print(x)

Foo.bar(10)
```

Both will output:

```
10
```